# How do you update Year field in the datetime column using another datetime column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two columns (Birth_date and Purchase_date) and would like to create a column (Birth_date_update) using following conditions

Conditions:

1. When Birth_date is later than Purchase_date, take birth_date.
2. When Birth_date is earlier than Purchase_date, Birth_date_update will take the year from purchase_date and override year from birth_date.
3. If the final value from condition 2 is still earlier than purchase_date, than find next birth_date anniversary that is bigger than purchase date.

Note: Condition 2 and 3 can be summarized as find earliest anniversary of birth_date greater than purchase_date.

```
Birth_date     purchase_date    Birth_date_update
2002-02-21     2006-05-11       2007-02-21
2004-01-18     2004-01-25       2005-01-18
2011-07-24     2011-04-09       2011-07-24
2006-12-16     2007-10-08       2007-12-16
2007-04-30     2008-03-14       2008-04-30
```

I have no idea how to code this.. please help!

Comment: Im bad with alignment : (

Comment: I don't understand this at all. Can you post the desired output for the sample data?

Comment: Birth_date_update is the desired output

Answer (score 0):

```
update my_table
  set birth_date_update = case 
    when birth_date > purchase_date then birth_date -- Condition 1
    when birth_date < purchase_date then dateadd(year, datediff(year, birth_date, purchase_date), birth_date) -- Condition 2
    when dateadd(year, datediff(year, birth_date, purchase_date), purchase_date) < purchase_date  
      then dateadd(year, 1, dateadd(year, datediff(year, birth_date, purchase_date), purchase_date)) end -- Condition 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Result from above answer doesn't seem to be correct. Looks like Condition 3 is not working consistent. So I added my answer

```
create table TAB1 (BD date, PD date, BDU date)

insert into TAB1 values 
('2002-02-21',     '2006-05-11',       NULL),
('2004-01-18',     '2004-01-25',       NULL),
('2011-07-24',     '2011-04-09',       NULL),
('2006-12-16',     '2007-10-08',       NULL),
('2007-04-30',     '2008-03-14',       NULL)

;with cc as (
    select BD, PD,
        case 
            when BD > PD then BD
            when BD < PD then cast(cast(year(PD) as varchar) + '-' + cast(month(BD) as varchar) + '-' + cast(day(BD) as varchar) as date)
        end as BDU
    from TAB1
)
, cc2 as (
    select BD, PD, 
        case 
            when BDU < PD then dateadd(day, 365, BDU)
            else BDU
        end as BDU
    from cc
)
update T1
set BDU = cc2.BDU 
from TAB1 T1
    inner join cc2 on cc2.BD = T1.BD and cc2.PD = T1.PD

select * from TAB1
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this! hope this works for every cases, I have couple of millions rows for this logic to work!

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Weird! The script I posted, it exactly what I am running!

Comment: yeah yours worked at it is but I cant apply it to my original table : (

Comment: maybe you have error when converting my queries into yours. please double check your query

Comment: When I run it, the final conversion to date from varchar is one giving me error... not the application of the query... 
In my table, 
cast(year(PD) as varchar) + '-' + cast(month(BD) as varchar) + '-' + cast(day(BD) as varchar) give me YYYY-M-DD for those have single number in the month. would this cause problem in the final step converting It back to date form?

Comment: I don't think so as this query works: select cast('2016-1-15' as date) and month is 1 character

Comment: there might be date format issue. let me dig into it

Comment: looks like the result from the cast(year(PD) as varchar) + '-' + cast(month(BD) as varchar) + '-' + cast(day(BD) as varchar)  is a character string that does not allow me from converting it to date or datetime... : ( im stuck.. sigh

Comment: My only guess is you have a date Feb 29 and adding 1 year to it, will raise error. Can you verify that? If that's the case, I'll fix it

Comment: ohhh I have 509 rows with birth_date dated in Feb 28.. would that raise an issue in sql as not possible for the date conversion?

Comment: I think Feb 28 is not a problem. Feb 29 can cause the issue. But try to filter Feb months to see if anything changes

Comment: OHH I have 186 rows with 2/29 in the year of 2008 and 2012.

Comment: So remove them from update using a where clause. Let me know the result. I hope this is the case.

Comment: I removed them by conditional code and it worked! so it is the leap year.. can you help me revise the code???

Comment: Gr8! I'm not at my desk but will update my answer shortly

Comment: Thank you so much!!! you are my life saver!!! Finally able to do my assignment! I actually wrote like 7 step query( involving mapping and ugly conditional calculations) and was hoping to do much simpler method of doing it. !!!!!!!

Comment: I am using SQL 2014 and don't get error. as you say it is different for you. anyway, I edited my answer, instead of dateadd(year, 1, ....) use dateadd(day, 365, ...). check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to be left out of this one.

Here is my answer

```
UPDATE dbo.BirthDateTable SET Birth_date_update =
CASE    WHEN Birth_date >= purchase_date THEN Birth_date -- Condition 1
        WHEN Birth_date < purchase_date
            THEN CASE
                WHEN CONVERT(Date  , CAST( DATEPART(YEAR,purchase_date) AS Varchar(4)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,Birth_date) AS Varchar(2)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, Birth_date) AS Varchar(2))) > purchase_date 
                THEN CONVERT(Date  , CAST( DATEPART(YEAR,purchase_date) AS Varchar(4)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,Birth_date) AS Varchar(2)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, Birth_date) AS Varchar(2))) -- Condition 2
                ELSE DATEADD(YEAR,1,CONVERT(Date  , CAST( DATEPART(YEAR,purchase_date ) AS Varchar(4)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,Birth_date) AS Varchar(2)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, Birth_date) AS Varchar(2)))) -- Condition 3
                END
        END
```

Here is a select example.

```
SELECT
CASE    WHEN Birth_date >= purchase_date THEN Birth_date -- Condition 1
        WHEN Birth_date < purchase_date
        THEN CASE
             WHEN CONVERT(Date  , CAST( DATEPART(YEAR,purchase_date) AS Varchar(4)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,Birth_date) AS Varchar(2)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, Birth_date) AS Varchar(2))) > purchase_date 
             THEN CONVERT(Date  , CAST( DATEPART(YEAR,purchase_date) AS Varchar(4)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,Birth_date) AS Varchar(2)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, Birth_date) AS Varchar(2))) -- Condition 2
             ELSE DATEADD(YEAR,1,CONVERT(Date  , CAST( DATEPART(YEAR,purchase_date ) AS Varchar(4)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,Birth_date) AS Varchar(2)) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, Birth_date) AS Varchar(2)))) -- Condition 3
             END
END
FROM dbo.BirthDateTable
```

Other post about above answer not being correct was written when the order of the answers was different on the page. I believe this answer meets the criteria.

@JamieHong, could you see if this select works on your system? I padded the month and day with zeros.

```
SELECT 
CASE    WHEN Birth_date >= purchase_date THEN Birth_date
        WHEN Birth_date < purchase_date
            THEN CASE
                WHEN CONVERT(Date  , CAST( DATEPART(YEAR,purchase_date) AS Varchar(4)) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,Birth_date) AS Varchar(2)),2) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, Birth_date) AS Varchar(2)),2)) > purchase_date 
                THEN CONVERT(Date  , CAST( DATEPART(YEAR,purchase_date) AS Varchar(4)) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,Birth_date) AS Varchar(2)),2) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, Birth_date) AS Varchar(2)),2))
                ELSE DATEADD(YEAR,1,CONVERT(Date  , CAST( DATEPART(YEAR,purchase_date ) AS Varchar(4)) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,Birth_date) AS Varchar(2)),2) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, Birth_date) AS Varchar(2)),2)))
                END
        END AS CalcDate 
FROM dbo.BirthDateTable
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the post,,, I do not know why im getting "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." error when I tried to apply this into my master table ; ( any idea?

Comment: I have all the fields defined as datatype Date. Ran it on SQL 2008 R2 without error. I will update my post with a select example, maybe that will shed some light on the issue.

Comment: When I run it, the final conversion to date from varchar is one giving me error... not the application of the query... In my table, I was able to run up to where it coverts the date into varchar, giving me YYYY-M-DD for those have single number in the month. would this cause problem in the final step converting It back to date form? I cant convert it back to date format. I have no trouble using your code for the sample I provided... all my date fields are also datatype date.

Comment: @MillhouseD, would you please explain what's wrong with my answer? I don't get your saying: "Other post about above answer not being correct was written when the order of the answers was different on the page"

Comment: @FLICKER I was not commenting on your answer. I was commenting that a different answer made the comment "the answer above" and due to the nature of stackoverflow our answers float around. I didn't want my answer to be dismissed because it landed above someone else's comment that "the answer above" has an issue. :)

Comment: No worries! I just thought there is something wrong in my answer an was going to know that